# Sencha plug-in not working with PhpStorm 2021.1?

Tags: extjs, phpstorm

With JetBrains PhpStorm the Sencha Ext JS plugin crash continually. At the end, IDE disables the plugin and I must go with previous version of JetBrains PhpStorm 2020.3 where plugin runs.

Comment: If plugin crashed -- contact the plugin author then. See the bottom of the https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7740-sencha-ext-js page for details.

Comment: Then Plugin Author now refers to stackoverflow as their official support forum. So this post is likely an attempt to do exactly what you suggest :)
Unfortunately this happens at least every year. The ExtJS/Sencha plugin always breaks with major web-/phpstorm updates